# Running a grails app on Amazon EC2 using set

Tags: grails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am running a grails application on an Amazon Linux EC2 instance by using the following command:

```
setsid grails run-war
```

I used this command so that I wouldn't have to keep my terminal windows open and it could continue to run and be available even when my windows computer is turned off which I used to log in to the amazon machine. The only problem is that it runs fine for a day and then it seems to shut down. I find every other day or so I have to re-issue the command. What is causing the app to quit and therefore needing to be restarted?

Comment: why don't you build a .war file and deploy that instead of using `run-war`? `run-war` is not supposed to be used for production deployment.

Comment: @Donal For now I am just running it for testing not fully production yet.

Comment: so use it for testing the same way as you will be using it in prod. This is the goal of testing, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments using `run-app` in any type of deployed environment isn't going to work the way you want it to.

The Grails documentation for [run-app](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/run-app.html) even includes the following statement (emphasis is mine):

> This target is not intended to be used for application **deployment**.
>   There are many optimizations implemented when generating a WAR file
>   for deployment that are not available to run-app since run-app is
>   optimized for developer productivity, not performance.

Note it says "deployment" not "production". Put simply, you are trying to use a screwdriver to hammer in a nail (the wrong tool for the job). The solution is to deploy your application in that environment and not use `run-app`.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is running your Grails app on EC2, Boxfuse comes with dead easy native support for [deploying Grails 3.x apps on EC2](https://boxfuse.com/blog/grails-aws) which does exactly that.

All you need to do is literally

```
boxfuse run my-grails3-app-1.0.jar
```

and Boxfuse will automatically

- fuse a minimal OS image tailor-made for your app (takes <10 seconds, image around 100 MB *including* the JVM & your app)
- push it to a secure online image repository
- convert it to an AMI in about 30 seconds
- create an elastic IP and assign a new domain to it
- create a security group with the correct ports open
- launch an instance of your AMI & make sure the healthchecks pass
- map the elastic ip (and the new domain) to your new instance

All updates are performed as **zero-downtime blue/green deployments**. And if you need more than one instance Boxfuse also supports ELBs, Auto-scaling and more.

Boxfuse analyses your native Grails 3 application.yml config and automatically extracts the ports and healthcheck information required for your app. This information is then used to correctly set up security groups and ELBs.

More info: https://boxfuse.com/getstarted/grails

*Disclaimer: I am the founder and CEO of Boxfuse*